# modualized shiny app ui renders all plots on top of one another

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, module

I have a shiny app, fully built, that I had built all in one script. Everything was working, the ui, etc. and I wanted to modularize the app to make the code a bit more readable. Now all the plots render on top of each other and I can't figure out why. I've tried using pageContainer, sidbarLayout, sidePanel and mainPanel, fluidPage, fixedPage, etc. and none have worked. I'm also using pagePiling with my main ui, so not sure if that has sometimes to do with it? Any help would be much appreciated!
Please find the full code here: https://github.com/eoefelein/COVID_Business_Recovery_and_Social_Capital/tree/master/socialCapitalEmployment

[image]
Here is what my ui code looks like:

```
ui <- tagList(
  pagePiling(
    center = TRUE,
    sections.color = c("#3333FF", "#E6E6E6"),
    menu = c(
      "Home" = "home",
      "Map" = "map",
      "Series" = "ts",
      "PCA" = "pca",
      "Predict" = "predict",
      "About" = "about"
    ),
    pageSectionImage(
      center = TRUE,
      img = "",
      menu = "home",
      h1(("title"), class = "header shadow-dark"),
      h3(
        class = "light footer",
        "by",
        tags$a("news-r", href = "https://news-r.org", class = "link")
      )
    ),
    pageSection(center = TRUE,
                menu = "map",
                mod_map_ui("map"),
                br()),
    pageSection(center = TRUE,
                menu = "ts",
                mod_ts_ui("ts"),
                br()),
    pageSection(center = TRUE,
                menu = "pca",
                mod_pca_ui("pca"),
                br()),
    pageSection(
      center = TRUE,
      menu = "predict",
      mod_predict_ui("predict"),
    ),
    pageSection(
      center = TRUE,
      menu = "about",
      h1("About", class = "header shadow-dark"),
      h2(
        class = "shadow-light",
        tags$a(
          "The code",
          href = "https://github.com/news-r/fopi.app",
          target = "_blank",
          class = "link"
        ),
        "|",
        tags$a(
          "The API",
          href = "https://github.com/news-r/fopi",
          target = "_blank",
          class = "link"
        )
      ),
      h3(
        class = "light footer",
        "by",
        tags$a("news-r", href = "https://news-r.org", class = "link")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Here is my first module's ui:

```
mod_map_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fluidPage(
    h1("Employment & Social Capital across the U.S by County"),
    center = TRUE,
    column(9, leafletOutput(ns("map"), height = "100vh")),
    column(
      3,
      shinyWidgets::radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = ns("idx"),
        label = "Metric",
        choices = c(unique(social_indices$name)),
        checkIcon = list(yes = icon("ok",
                                    lib = "glyphicon"))
      )
    )
  ))
}
```

And here is my second module's ui:

```
mod_ts_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    fixedPage(
      h2("Employment by County", align = "center"),
      fixedRow(
        column(
          4,
          selectizeInput(
            inputId = ns("dataset"),
            label = "Choose a county:",
            choices = c(unique(employment["countyfips"])),
            multiple = TRUE,
            selected = "Travis County, Texas",
            options = list(create = TRUE)
            )
          ),
        column(
          8, (echarts4r::echarts4rOutput(ns("ts_plot")))
          )
        )
      )
    )
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post a full [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can help you.

Comment: @YBS here is the link to the full code uploaded to github. Thanks for your help! https://github.com/eoefelein/COVID_Business_Recovery_and_Social_Capital/tree/master/socialCapitalEmployment

Comment: Quite sure this problem arises from `pagePiling`, not something that can happen with the usual `fluidPage` and so on.

Comment: For plots you could use `pageSectionPlot()`, instead of `pageSection()`.

Answer (score 0):

okay, so I fixed it and what I think fixed it was specifying a color for each section:

```
pagePiling(
    center = TRUE,
    sections.color = c("#7b959c", "#445768","#b9bdc9","#f6e7ea","#e2e2e2","#1e4356"),
    menu = c(
      "Home" = "home",
      "Map" = "map",
      "Series" = "ts",
      "PCA" = "pca",
      "Predict" = "predict",
      "About" = "about"
    ),
```

Very strange, but after I did that, each plot presented as it should, in it's own section. Hope this helps someone in the future!